# Unable to change a commit message after using rebase and rewording the message

Tags: git, bitbucket, rebase

There is a git commit for which I want to change the commit message (add a prefix to the existing message to be exact). The repository has been pushed to the remote bitbucket.

The commit is a very old one. I performed `git rebase -i HEAD~100`  I changed the `pick` to `reword` and then the editor allowed me to modify the commit message.
There were about 50+ conflicts after that with rebase operations.
Probably I made some mistakes and now I don't see the commit message changed. Not sure what went wrong.
There were a lot of steps and it was easy to make mistakes.
I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.
Any ideas on how to go about doing it or thoughts on why the commit message was not modified?
Is there a way to avoid rebases and change the commit message?

Comment: Were there some merge done in your tree after the bad-worded commit? are you the only one to commit/push there, or do you have peers also pushing things?

Comment: Where are you looking that the commit message didn't change?

Comment: That much conflicts to change **one** commit message? Seriously? Sorry to ask but..... why? If it's for JIRA detection of commits linked to a ticket, I'd suggest explaning it in a comment and putting something in place to avoid future similar mistakes. (A `commit-msg` [hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), for instance?)

Comment: @JimRedmond I am looking at the bitbucket (remote) commit logs

Comment: @OznOg I just checked and after the bad-worded commit I do see around 12 commits made by 2 other people. Maybe that is causing so much mess?

Answer (score 0):

> Probably I made some mistakes and now I don't see the commit message changed. Not sure what went wrong.

... is not a diagnosable problem. Only you can find out what you did. If it had no effect it's safe to do it again, this time recording the steps and checking the current state before each one.

> Is there a way to avoid rebases and change the commit message?

Just revert the commit and then re-apply with a fixed message? Rewriting history is a bad idea in general and you haven't given a fraction of the information needed to judge whether your situation is an exception.

Comment: reverting the commit won't change the original commit message in the commit logs, it will just add a new commit

Comment: Nothing can ever mutate a commit, only create a new one. Changing the message changes the hash, which means its a new commit object. All you can do is put your new commit at the correct place in your commit history.

Comment: That's interesting. What do you suggest to do in this case? It seems that bitbucket is not allowing to merge the current branch to the master due to a commit message that is not compliant. 1. One way is merge all the commits after this commit and before this commit to master and then apply the changes to the current commit manually. 2. Another could be if I could squash merge into master so it creates only a single commit there. It's somewhat confusing what should I do here

Comment: You still haven't shown clearly what you did, what the result was, what you wanted the result to look like, _or_ your starting state. You need to edit that into your question if you hope to see a detailed answer.